# Extending Hive: writing a UDF that does both Map and Reduce operations

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, user-defined-functions

I am working on a project to extend Hive to support some image processing functions.

To do this, we need to read in an `image`, break it up into multiple files, pass each into a separate Map task that does some processing on it and then reduce them back into one image to be returned to the user.

To do this, we had planned to implement a `UDF` that would call a `MapReduce` task in Hadoop. However, from what we understand the `UDF` would only operate `either on the Map side OR the Reduce side of the HQL query`, while we need it to ideally '`bridge the gap`' between the Map and the Reduce side.

The `Hive documentation` isn't the most helpful, and I was looking for some pointers on where to start looking for more information about this.
Please feel free to ask more questions if I haven't been clear enough in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into HIPI (Hadoop Image Processing Inteface) might give you a start. 
Particularly, the example on computing the Principal Components of a bunch of images might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Use UDAF (User Defined Aggragate Function). Which has sort of map and reduce phase.